# How to use two group by statement in one select statement in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with three columns. (Column_A, Column_B, Column_C)

And the data has following structure in table is as follows:

```
Column_A  |  Column_B  |  Column_C
----------------------------------
  Jeeva   |  football  |   1
  Jeeva   |  football  |   2
  Jeeva   |  football  |   3
  Jeeva   |  handball  |   5
  Jeeva   |  handball  |   1
  Jeeva   |  handball  |   7
  Jeeva   |  handball  |   2
  Jeeva   |  voleyball |   1
  Jeeva   |  voleyball |   2
 Bharathi |  voleyball |   10
 Bharathi |  voleyball |   7
 Bharathi |  voleyball |   2
```

I wanted the following as a result:

```
Column_A  |  Column_B  |  Column_C
----------------------------------
  Jeeva   |  football  |   3
  Jeeva   |  handball  |   7
  Jeeva   |  voleyball |   2
 Bharathi |  voleyball |   10
```

Desired result: Find the maximum score value in Column_C for each individual sport in Column_B the user in Column_A has played

I wrote the query as follows in Bigquery,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM `project.dataset.individual_results` a 
RIGHT JOIN
(SELECT column_a, column_b, MAX(column_c) AS max_val FROM `project.dataset.individual_results` GROUP BY column_a GROUP BY column_b) b 
ON a.column_a = b.column_a AND a.column_b= b.max_val WHERE a.column_c IS NOT NULL
```

I am getting an error because of the second `Group By` statement.

Error message:

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword GROUP
```

How to resolve this issue and get the desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY column_a GROUP BY column_b` - should be just `GROUP BY column_a, column_b`.

But I also think you don't need JOIN at all, and the second subquery gives you the exact result you described:

```
SELECT column_a, column_b, MAX(column_c) AS max_val 
FROM `project.dataset.individual_results` 
GROUP BY column_a, column_b
```